# Python: Theory as to why I can't Do: print(i.extend(j))

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python Theoretical Question 
I'd like to learn theory behind why "print(i.extend(j))" DOESN'T work.
It's OUTPUT is: "None". 
print(j) DOES work (It's OUTPUT is:  "[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]")

```
i = [1, 2, 3]
j = [4, 5, 6]
k = [7, 8, 9]
# I'd like to learn theory as to why following doesn't work
# OUTPUT is: "None"  
print(i.extend(j))
# Following does work (OUTPUT is:  "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]")
j.extend(k)
print(j)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer valutah and Tony.  I'm new to Python and stackoverflow.  I looked on stackoverflow for a while and couldn't find anything about the list.extend method.

Could someone tell me how to find info about the list.extend method using search on the python.org site?   I've spent 30 minutes and can't do it.  Thank you, Mike

Comment: I agree, sometimes it's hard to search the official documentation. The `extend` method is covered [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) and in the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). You could also use the built-in `help` function: `help('list.extend')`.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple -

extend doesn't return anything, and any function that doesn't return a value is taken to have returned None.

Comment: why the down vote - what was wrong with my answer ?

Comment: (not the downvoter) I think it is because the duplicate clearly explains this therefore probably no need to answer and let the voting take care of closing as such.

Comment: A silly reason to down vote then - ah well - people like their own rules ...

Comment: It's not a silly reason. If a question is clearly a dupe, don't duplicate content by answering - just vote for the dupe and move on.